# MAMP not connecting to localhost

Tags: mysql, wordpress, localhost, mamp, osx-yosemite

Just updated MAMP to version 3.2.1 on Yosemite. Both Apache and MySQL servers are green but when I go to my localhost I keep getting: This webpage is not available ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED in browser (Chrome). I’ve tried incognito browsing and Firefox with the same result, tried both the MAMP default port settings and ports 80 & 3306, tried a reinstall of MAMP and rolling back to previous install of MAMP; all without success.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this…it’s starting to drive me crazy!

Answer (score 18):

Possible Thoughts;

- In your /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ folder, is there something in there for your browser to load?  Some sort of index.html or index.php file?  Could it have gotten removed accidentally?
- When you launch MAMP and go to Preferences -> Ports, what is the Apache port?  You mentioned you tried the default (8888/8889) and 80/3306, but could the port number somehow have gotten changed?
- Is there any chance that some other Apache service is running?  This is unlikely as you mentioned that MAMP shows Apache status as green, but it could be worth stopping MAMP, opening Terminal and doing *sudo apachectl stop*, returning to MAMP and changing the ports to 80/3306, then returning to Terminal and doing *sudo apachectl restart*.  Then return to MAMP and start services again.
- If none of the above work, what if you set the Apache port in MAMP's preferences to something random, like 8712, and then try http://localhost:8712/ to see if it loads.

Let us know if you've tried those already!

Comment: Thanks. Changing the port resolved my problem. There's no error shown.

Comment: Thank you very much! That last bullet point was the fix for me. O.O

Comment: I had the same problem and changing ports to 80/3306 solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue. If 127.0.0.1 is working then you just need to point localhost to 127.0.0.1. Edit /etc/hosts file (requires sudo) and include
`127.0.0.1 localhost`

That resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

This still happens occasionally when updating macOS.

Going through all local Wordpress sites and changing the dev url isn't ideal, though necessary when changing the port.

What rather solved the issue for me was restarting Apache as suggested by @ZbadhabitZ, keeping original port number:

`sudo apachectl restart`

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I had Docker Desktop running at the same time; I shut this down and it started working so it must have been a port conflict.